# I want to swap the linkedlist terms pairwise, my code is giving me Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to swap the linkedlist terms pairwise.

Here is my code. It is giving me Segmentation Fault-core dumped

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;
void insert(struct node *n)
{
    int  num;
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(n==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {

        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }

}
int main()
{
    struct node *n;
    head=NULL;
    n=head;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {

        insert(n);
        n=head;
    }
    display(n);
    pairswap(n);
    display(n);

}
void display(struct node *n)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=n;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void pairswap(struct node *n)
{
    struct node *temp,*temp1,*temp2;
    temp=n;
    temp1=temp->next;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        int tempnum;
        tempnum=temp->data;
        temp->data=temp1->data;
        temp1->data=tempnum;
        if(temp==n)
        {
            head=temp;
            head->next=temp1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp2->next=temp;
            temp2->next->next=temp1;
        }
        temp2=temp1;
        temp=(temp->next)->next;
        temp1=temp->next;
    }
    n=head;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it under gdb?

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about the debuggers.

Somewhere at the end of the list the value of 

`(temp->next)->next` 

is NULL, which you are putting it in variable temp.

Before making this assignment `temp1=temp->next`, you need to check if temp is NULL and take proper action.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pairswap function. In the while loop you are using the condition:
while(temp!=NULL)

and inside the loop you are assigning:
temp=(temp->next)->next

which will get crashed on the second last node since you are trying to dereference NULL pointer.

Use the following condition:
while((temp->next)->next!=NULL)
or
while (temp1->next != NULL)